# rails gem chosen and mailboxes new message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen, mailboxer

I'm trying to implement chosen gem with mailboxes for new messages. but the select box always appears empty.

**messages/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "messages", action: "create", 
:class => "form-horizontal"}, method:  :post) do %>     
    <h3>Reply</h3>
    <%= select :recipients,
       User.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] },
       { class: 'chosen-select' }
    %>
    <%= text_area_tag :body,nil, class: 'form-control'%>
    <%= submit_tag 'Send message', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Messages.js.coffee

```
$('#messages_recipients').chosen()
```

**js errors:**

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery (chosen.jquery.js, line 524)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ (messages.js, line 2)
```

Can anyone see a problem ? I'm guessing I'm just missing something small, it has been annoying for a rather long time ;/

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include choosen js file. Just add `//= require chosen-jquery` to you application.js.

Comment: No thats not it, the file is included and loaded

Comment: Ohh, Can you make sure you included jquery before chosen.